# transform the dataframe and change the grouping

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
        level_1
75016   0,1,2,3
75017   3,7,10
75018   2,10
```

which the first column is the id of disease
and the number that on second column is the id of patients

I want to create a dataframe but the patient in the rows and disease id in the columns
the output:

```
0             75016   
1             75016
2             75016        75018 (each disease in a column if possible )        
3             75016        75017
7             75017
10            75017        75018
```

how can I do this please?

Comment: can any one help me please?

Comment: I think it would be better to make three columns of 75016, 75017, 75018 and set these numbers for each patient, how do you look at it?